# Convert VB.NET code to PHP

Tags: php, vb.net, md5

I have code to MD5 string in VB.Net, but i want convert it to php with same value return 

VB.Net Code :

```
Public Shared Function ConverFileName(ByVal FileName As String) As String
        Dim str2 As String = ""
        Dim provider As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider
        Try 
            Dim buffer As Byte() = provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(FileName))
            Dim num2 As Integer = (buffer.Length - 1)
            Dim i As Integer = 0
            Do While (i <= num2)
                str2 = (str2 & StringType.FromByte(buffer(i)))
                i += 1
            Loop
        Catch exception1 As Exception
            ProjectData.SetProjectError(exception1)
            Dim exception As Exception = exception1
            ProjectData.ClearProjectError
        End Try
        Return str2
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already a inbuilt function to calculate the MD5 Hash of file in PHP.

[`md5_file($filename)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5-file.php)

Example #1 Usage example of `md5_file()`

```
<?php
$file = 'php-5.3.0alpha2-Win32-VC9-x64.zip';

echo 'MD5 file hash of ' . $file . ': ' . md5_file($file);
?>
```

or if you need to find the MD5 Has for a string then

http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php

```
<?php
$str = 'apple';

echo 'MD5 hash of ' . $str. ': ' . md5($str);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

can u help change from vb net to php to

```
Function Enkrip(pwd As String) As String
    Dim s As String
    s = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(pwd)
        s = s + Chr(Asc(Mid(pwd, i, 1)) + 32)
    Next i
    Enkrip = s
End Function
```